# Symbols on the end of a line

Tags: symbols

is it possible to remove these symbols, and if it is, how am I goding to do that? 
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Window | Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors --> Show
>   whitespace characters

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps:

```
$ dos2unix file.java
```

or

```
$ unix2dos file.java
```